# Feature selection while retaining a specified feature

Tags: classification, feature-selection

Pardon if this question is very basic, but I am not able to find any solution for my problem. I am trying to run a feature selection scheme on N features for my classification model, however I want one of these features to always appear in the model. Is there a way to run feature selection on the remaining N-1 variables?

The feature I want to retain is categorical.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the feature selection routine you choose to use.
Matlab's `sequentialfs`, a wrapper based sequential feature selection routine, allows you to force a given feature to remain in the feature set with the `keepin`  input parameter.
I am sure R or equivalent languages also offer equivalent functionality.

Comment: The [penalized](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/penalized/index.html) R package offers similar option (see argument `unpenalized=`), although it deals with L1/L2 penalization schemes, and not FS *per se*.